# Is there any way to block users from downloading things onto the computer?

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows-xp

I don't want people to be downloading anything they want because in the past, there has been too much p*rn downloaded, viruses and trojans of all sorts (I had to clean up a ton of this crap) and programs downloaded and installed even on restricted user account in Windows XP.

Comment: **Download**, **save** or **run programs**? Big difference. Also, which OS is this about? A specific technique that works on Linux won't help you any on Windows XP, and what works on Windows XP might not work on Windows 7.

Comment: will you solve problem regarding to downloading

Comment: Use a firewall or proxy, configured with either a blacklist or a whitelist. A whitelist will probably be easier unless you have an exhaustive list of the sites you want to block (just configure the whitelist to allow only those sites of which you approve). Do expect major breakage and realize that it won't be bullet-proof.

Comment: i just started my career in system admin i don't know how to setup firewall or proxy etc will you please give me simple n effective way to solve this type of problem... thanks

Comment: There is no simple or effective way to solve this. Other than not letting them online in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup a **squid-proxy** on another machine and make everyone use the squid-proxy. This way you can control what's being served to the user.
then you can use blacklists to block nsfw stuff. there should be plenty of blacklists for squid flying around to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you can restrict users from downloading things but you can get security programs to block the websites that you don't want therefore making it impossible to download things. Also, what is this for?
If it is

### For businesses

You can use one of these programs that I found:

- http://www.currentware.com/
- http://www1.k9webprotection.com/

Or

### For home

You can use Microsoft's built in [parental controls](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-za/windows7/set-up-parental-controls) but I don't know if it blocks websites and there is also [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-za/windows-live/family-safety-child-kid-protect-filter-sites-chat-faq) that I found.

I hope this helps.